# Simple text and image slider

Tags: jquery

I've been looking for a slider that can slide whatever kind of content that I want to enter.
I tried out various Wordpress plugins, but most of them only can slide Wordpress posts or images only with a small caption.
I'm looking for something like the [WP Photo Slider 50](http://www.gopiplus.com/work/2011/06/02/wordpress-plugin-wp-photo-slider-50/#comment-52504).
Unfortunately this slider doesn't work in my theme, though as there is a jquery conflict and I have no clue how to modify the plugin so that there won't be a conflict (if possible at all).

I was wondering if somebody could help me find a slider plugin similar to the one above, direct me to a "how to creat a slider yourself" website or help me figure out how to get rid of the jquery conflict with the plugin mentioned above.

My website (still heavily under construction): [here](http://www.zoomingjapan.com)

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [jQuery Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/) for all my slider needs. It supports sliding of any type of content, and content can slide horizontally and vertically.

JQuery Tools and JQuery Scrollable are free, open sourced, and well documented. The support forums can be very useful if you are having problems implementing scrollable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will have a look at it and see if I can get it to work as it requires quite a lot of coding I'm not (yet) familiar with.

Comment: I think it's to difficult for me to set it up. I don't have the necessary knowledge it seems, but thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: no problem. sorry it didn't work out for you.

Comment: Hello again. I tried again and it seems to work. Well, I still have several problems, but with a little bit of help I might be able to fix that, too, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I made an own slider, based on [Slides (slideshow plugin for jQuery)](http://slidesjs.com)

Usage example:

**functions.php**

```
function featured_posts( $category='featured', $limit='-1' ) {
    $category = get_category_by_slug( $category );
    $posts = get_posts( array( 'category' => $category->cat_ID , 'orderby' => 'rand' , 'DESC' , 'numberposts' => $limit ));
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $post_title = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($post->post_title));

        echo '
            <div class="slide">
                <div class="slide-title">'.$post->post_title.'</div>
                <div class="slide-content">'.$post->post_content.'</div>
            </div>';
    }
}
```

**footer.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery().ready(function() {
        jQuery('#slides').slides({
            play: 4000,
            hoverPause: false,
            generatePagination: true,
        });
    });
</script>
```

You also have to enroll the slides.js in your functions.php, for example:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'slides.jquery.js' , get_option( 'siteurl' ) . '/wp-content/themes/YOUR THEME/js/slides.jquery.js' , array('jquery') , '1.0' );
```

Comment: And instead of posts, I also could put in random content, anything I like? :)

Comment: @japanworm: Of course, why not? :)

Comment: Hello again. I'm a little bit confused. How to I call the slider in my template fiel and how do I have to modify the function.php when I want to use the slider for whatever content I wanna put into the "divs" and not featured content? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The code above is made to display posts of a category. You can call it from your theme with: <div id="slides"> <?php featured_posts('CATEGORY_SLUG'); ?> </div>. You need to modify the function above as putting your content inside the slides div in the cycle, but what exactly you want to add into it, that cannot be done as posts in a category? I can help with exact code as well, but please send me a mail with the detailed and exact question if you're still stuck. For a working example, please see: http://webportfolio.hu , the slider on the front page is made this way.

Comment: Hello again. I tried once again from zero what you described here. It messed up my function.php. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm so desperate by now :( Thank you for your offer. I don't mind talking here, but if you give me your mail addy, then that's okay with me, too. I really doubt I can get this to work. I've tried for many days without any good results now! :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Anything Slider](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery_image_slider_plugin) from **Chris Coyier** and others.
There's also a WordPress  plugin for it - [AnythingSlider for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/anythingslider-for-wordpress/)

Recently released and my personal favorite is the [Orbit slider](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery_image_slider_plugin) from **Zurb / Smashing Magazine**. Afaik there's no WordPress clone yet but I'm using it in my own plugin and it works great. It's not something I could release until more work is done but I can offer a helping hand / some code snippets if you would decide to use it.

Both can slide `div`s and `li`s with **any kind of content** inside them.

Comment: Can you use Orbit slider for anything other than images? :)

Comment: @japanworm Have your read the last sentence from my answer? :) Yes you can.

Comment: Sorry for some reason I only read about the "div" and "li" part :) Thanks, I'll try and see if I can work with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Would the Nivo Slider work?  I have found it to be very helpful when having a similar jQuery conflict.
http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

They have a free version.

Comment: The nivo slider - at least the plugins for it that I've found only seem to work for images, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yaa I also recommend the NIVO slider, here is a tutorial on how to integrate it with wordpress

http://webstutorial.com/wordpress-jquery-slide-show-how-to-add-wordpress-jquery-slide-show-wordpress-jquery-nivo-slider/content-management-system-cms/wordpress-cms